# Martingale Poisson

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, poisson-process

Can somebody help me with working out:
$$E[(N_{t}-\lambda t)^2\mid F_{s}]$$ where $N_{t}$ is a Poisson process and $F_{s}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $N_{s}$, $0 \leq s < t$.

Comment: This is in dire need of context.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** The (homogeneous) Poisson process has stationary independent increments, so write: $$N_t=N_s+(N_t-N_s)=N_s+N_{t-s}$$ and use that

1. $E[N_s \mid F_s]=N_s$, since $N_s$ is known at time $s$
2. $E[N_{t-s}\mid F_s]=E[N_{t-s}]$, since $N_{t-s}$ is independent from what happened up to time $s$
3. $N_{t-s} \sim$ Poisson$(λ(t-s))$, in order to calculate $E[N_{t-s}]$ and $E[N_{t-s}^2]$.

Comment: Thank you! Is it handy to work out the brackets first?

Comment: @RoosJansen You mean to write $(N_t-λt)^2=N_t^2-2λtN_t+λ^2t^2$? Yes, this is the first thing to do!